# Is an compareTo method a self association in UML?

Tags: java, architecture, uml

I'm currently making an package and class diagram. I have a class that uses the compareTo method. My question is when I model it, do I have to make a self association? If so, is the self association a dependency line or just a normal line?

Example of the code:

```
public class Example implements Comparable<Example> {

    private String name;

    public Example(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Example) {
            return ((Example) obj).name.equals(name);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Example o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.getNaam());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is no self-relationship. You list it as method for the given class.

Comment: @Turing85 But i also use the class in the parameter.

Comment: Loosely speaking associations are modeled as fields of a class (either a field with the type of the associated class or a field with a collection of elements of the type of the associated class.) Your method parameter is neither of these.

Comment: There is no hard definition (at least none I can find) as to what counts as an association and what does not. But [in general, instance- and class members may lead to some kind of association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Scopes).

Comment: Citing the above mentioned wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram): "[A class diagram] is a type of static structure diagram that describes the structure of a system". Method arguments are better fitted for one of the "Behavioral UML diagrams" like a sequence diagram that shows the interactions between objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a class knows itself (which is self-evident) you simply write it this way:

[image]

Note: I left out most of the operations.

A self reference is used if you have an attribute which is typed with the class itself. A simple example is `Employee` which references a `manager` that is an `Employee` itself:

[image]

To elaborate on this: as you have seen, associations are just another rendering for attributes. If you use a typed parameter which is not represented by an attribute you would create a dependency like in the following picture.

[image]